# Performance impact of lowering 30FPS Webcam images to 25FPS in FFmpeg live Encoder

Tags: ffmpeg, encoding, webcam

I'm writing some infos about FFmpeg Live Media Encoder and wasn't able to answer this question or find some information about.

Assume i have a Webcam that sends 30 FPS to my PC and i use ffmpeg as Live Encoder that will only send 25 Images per Second to the Video Plattform (a lowering of 5fps).

1) Will have lowering from 30 to 25 a more a negative impact than just let it be 30fps? (excluding more bandwith that will be needed)
2) Will it result in some further quality issues instead just have less framerate i mean maybe something like Interpolation issues and effects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between 30 and 25 is visually small enough as to be unnoticeable.
There may be a slight decrease in the size of the video file, but that entirely
depends on the codec that is used (you could just as well have increased size).

It should only be an issue when the computer playing the video is weak and requires
all the help it can get, so the player will have less to decode.
If the player is too slow, you will have glitches when frames are skipped.
But with modern computers and video adapters there shouldn't be a problem.

If you wish to see visually the difference, hop to
[25 fps vs 30 fps Railfanning](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fP1YWuLfsrs)
where the same video is shown in both modes (I failed to see the difference).